# Query regarding looping a response data array using async await

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I am working with an existing class components based React application and was dumbfounded when I spent almost 3 hours to figure out the root cause of the following code snippet.

In **componentDidMount** which is async btw, I am calling backend API designed with Node.js using **axios** like this

**(**Note** state below is in Class Component which I skipped for obvious reasons)**

```
state = {
  grades = [];
}

try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/assignments/getStudentAssignment/${this.props.studentId}`
    );

    const assignments = res.data.assignment.assignments;
    
    assignments.forEach((assignment) => {
       this.setState({grades: [...this.state.grades, assignment.grade]})
    }))

} catch (err) {
    'some logic'
}
```

Where *res.data.assignment.assignments* is an array of each student assignments, and from each assignment I am pushing a new grade in *grades array state*. In console.log using Chrome browser I saw that the grades array had 8 elements but I couldn't view them in console.log, and the length of array was also set to 0.
I consoled assignment within forEach array and also set a counter in order to see that is forEach looping through the entire array or just first element. Console.log only printed first counter number and also first array element

I figured out that since the assignments is an array of promises that are yet to be resolved, I cannot loop through the entire array, and then I changed my code to this

```
await assignments.forEach((assignment) => {
       this.setState({grades: [...this.state.grades, assignment.grade]})
}))
```

And viola, it worked like a charm but I am confused on a couple of things.

1. Isn't await supposed to resolve promise res.data.assignment.assignments,
   meaning I can loop through resolved array data
2. Why did forEach work for only first element of
   res.data.assignment.assignments if the array was yet to be resolved?

I tried on MDN, by creating a sample array in a promise and then looping through the contents of array in a then chain where each element was printed on console perfectly. Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT**
I have changed the original code, axios returns an assignment object which also contains an array of assignments

I worked with the following code once again without await, and its working fine. This is the second time, I had trouble with React setState, first time setState wasn't firing for some reason, and then after deleting node_modules and installing all required packages it worked, even though it wasted a day

```
   state = {
     grades = [];
   }

   try {
       const res = await axios.get(
          `/assignments/getStudentAssignment/${this.props.studentId}`
       );

       const assignments = res.data.assignment.assignments;

       assignments.forEach((assignment) => {
         this.setState({grades: [...this.state.grades, assignment.grade]})
       }))
    } catch (err) {
    'some logic'
    }
```

Comment: Something strange is going on. Array.forEach returns undefined, so you can't await it, and it should't make a difference. And axios should have returned a parsed json object, not an array of promises. Is maybe setState ansyc?

Comment: await is required for http based requests response for [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#rewriting_promise_code_with_asyncawait) but forEach working for first array element is confusing and yes since componentDidMount is async, setState within componentDidMount is also async I think

Comment: That `await` makes absolutely no sense. However, your bigger problem is the repeated `this.setState`, which is (or can be) asynchronous, so you should not rely on `this.state.grades`. Use the callback form. Or just use `this.setState({grades: this.state.grades.concat(assignments.map(assignment => assignment.grade))})`

Comment: @Bergi been scratching my head since then, because when I removed await from forEach later on, it is working fine. As for repeated this.setState, I agree but there are a couple of other setState involved within forEach array which pertains to different states. But the problem arised when I was getting this.state.grades as an array with objects but I couldn't expand those objects in console window, and get this, when I hardcoded it like this `this.state.grades[0]` I was able to view first object with all its properties